# Webview can't load in a popup windows store app (facebook login page)

Tags: c#, windows-8

I got the sample code from CameraCaptureUI in msdn site. Then I added a function to call popup of a facebook login page. But the popup showed nothing. 
I tested the facebook code with a new project and it worked properly.
Have anyone know why this popup can't display anything?

```
        popup.Child = new FacebookLogin();
        popup.IsOpen = true;
        App.fbevents.FBEvent += fbevents_FBEvent;
```